# get the system date in the same format as the system

Tags: java, date

I want my java program to take the system date format .

Ex: when i change the  date format in the system from `mm-dd-yy` to `yyyy-MM-dd`.
I want my java program to pull the short date format from the system and display in my program.

Again if I change the system format to `M/D/YY`, my java program to display this.

I tried few options like ,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
System.out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );
```

this always prints `mm/dd/yy` inspite of having `yyyy-mm-dd` format in the system.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not certain it's possible, Java uses the locale information to make decisions about which format it should use for `DateFormat`, it doesn't use any of the system configuration, which would be nice

Answer (score 3):

Use [SimpleDateFormat.toLocalizedPattern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#toLocalizedPattern--)

From the Java Docs:

> Returns a localized pattern string describing this date format.

Comment: This always returns, M/d/yy h:mm a
date = 7/29/15 12:01 PM    But my system format is yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: you are referring to the Operating System format? [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711925/how-can-i-so-date-and-time-formatting-in-java-that-respects-the-users-os-settin) question might be of help in that.

Comment: I tried possible options provided in that link, but its not working as expected.

Comment: The link doesnt specify the exact solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyy");
Date date = new Date();
```

and then simply print

```
dateFormat.format(date);
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked. The question was how to use the configured system date format, not how to a DateFormat.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getDateFromLongformat(long dateInLong) {

    Date date = new Date(dateInLong);
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String dateText = df.format(date);

    return dateText;
}
```

Comment: Explain what your code does and why it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We were using following approach for this

1. Identify the timezone of the system
2. have a dateformat mapping to preferred timezone
3. use the dateformat from the mapping to display the date.

Step 2 was basically a properties file, where we mapped the timezone and preferred date format.

Answer (score 0):

You can't retrieve the date format used in your operating system using Java but you can format the date based on the locale using `SimpleDateFormat` class.

Refer Doc: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html](http://SimpleDateFormat)