# How to get system calendar setting about the first day of a week in Javascript or Java?

Tags: javascript, java

I am trying to implement a feature that can obtain the user setting of which day is the first day of a week in his/her environment. I tried Java's getFirstDayofWeek() method but it seems to depend on the locale. For example, if the user is in US then it will return "Sunday", and if he/she is in France then it will return "Monday". However, Windows allows a user to select any day as the first day of a week, regardless of the locale. So my problem now is how to get his personal setting with code? I am struggling on this issue for a while. Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711925/how-can-i-so-date-and-time-formatting-in-java-that-respects-the-users-os-settin