# Get User's date and time formatting using java based on the OS date,time setting that they have made

Tags: java, windows

i am working on an application that needs date,time formatting that the user has set in their windows machine..i tried based on their locale but some user have set their own date format..so is there a way to get the format that they have used in their OS...

Comment: This answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/54630572/972773

Comment: the links whatever you have mentioned as duplicate doesn't have proper solution..please help ..thanks in advance.