# How to display the proper localized DateTime format?

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I am writing a JavaFx program that shows the Time and Date format of Windows. That means when I change the language of Windows, the program should show the new time and date format. For example in some locations, the time format is like this:

30.12.2018

and in other locations, it's displayed like this:

12.30.2018

I tried with LocalDateTime Class in Java, but that makes no sense, because that class doesn't have Timezone information.

```
private void init()
{
    button = new Button("Update");
    button.setFont(Font.font(null,FontWeight.BOLD,15));
    setBottom(button);
    setAlignment(button, Pos.CENTER);
    setPadding(new Insets(15));

    ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
    label = new Label();
    label.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD,20));
    label.setTextFill(Color.RED);
    label.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

    text = ldt.toString();
    label.setText(text);

    gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.add(label, 0, 0);
    gridPane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    setCenter(gridPane);        
}
```

German:

[image]

English:

[image]

How can I display this correctly?

Comment: Then don't use a _Local_DateTime. Can you elaborate on your problem?

Comment: I tried to explain my problem. when i change the timezone of windows (Language) the program should show me this change. but localdatetime has a predefined format and does not have to do with windows timezone. the Localdatetime shows me every time the same format such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30. but when i change the location of windows, the windows shows me a new date format like this : 03/12/2007

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711925/how-can-i-set-date-and-time-formatting-in-java-that-respects-the-users-os-setti

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Wrong class: `LocalDateTime`

**Never use `LocalDateTime` to track an actual moment.** Lacking any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC, a `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment. A `LocalDateTime` can know “noon on the 23rd of January 2019” but it does *not* know if you mean noon in Tokyo Japan, noon in Tunis Tunisia, or noon in Montréal Québec — three very different moments, each separated by several hours.

The word “Local” in `LocalDateTime` means *any* locality, or *every* locality. But it does *not* mean any one particular locality.

## Correct class: `ZonedDateTime`

To track moments use either `Instant` (always in UTC) or `ZonedDateTime` (or perhaps `OffsetDateTime`).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ; // Capture the current moment as seen through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone). 
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from a zone to UTC, if needed. An `Instant` is always in UTC by definition.
```

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

## Auto-localize

The `DateTimeFormatter` class can automatically localize while generating text representing the value of date-time object.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;   // Or Locale.US, Locale.JAPAN, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
                                       .withLocale( l );
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

Be clear that locale and time zone have *nothing* to do with one another – orthogonal issues. A engineer from Québec attending a conference in India might want to see the schedule of events presented in her native French language with Canadian cultural norms, and with the date-times shown in the local Indian time zone.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: This is a stellar answer and I wish there was a way for it to get more attention than getting buried in some random question.

Comment: @corsiKa There is - bounties. You can post a bounty to the question and pick one of the default reasons: "reward an existing answer". It will bump the post and also make the post appear higher up in the bounty filter of questions the closer it gets to the bounty's expiration date, and will also further reward the answerer by awarding an extra amount of 50 to 500 rep on top of whatever rep they earn.

Comment: @Basil Note that people are talking about your answers which may be attracting meta-effect voting, and the general concensus seems to be going against you adding the same boilerplate text across multiple posts. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380536/same-aside-added-to-the-end-of-multiple-answers?cb=1

Comment: @TylerH Oh for sure. That will do it a little. Better, though, is for regulars to either close dupes or otherwise link to it.