# How to change Java toLocalizedPattern() date format in windows?

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino, xpages-ssjs

My below java code prints the date format as shown below.

```
var pattern:java.lang.String = (new java.text.SimpleDateFormat()).toLocalizedPattern();
print("Pattern===>"+pattern)
```

[image].

Expected Date Format: dd/MM/yyyy
Actual Date format: M/d/yy

I am not sure from where this date format is getting picked up. I have changed all the settings at windows level. My domino date setting also changed as shown below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Do we have any specific java policy needs to be updated with dd/MM/yyyy date format?

Comment: Isn’t your server in charge of the format and not the client? Would need reboot

Comment: Thanks for replying. All these pictures from Server only. I did reboot several times both domino and windows. still same format is coming.  NotesInternational class is returning "DMY" properly. Only Java has this format issue.

Comment: "*where this date format is getting picked up*" : as explained in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#%3Cinit%3E()): "*Constructs a `SimpleDateFormat` using the default pattern and date format symbols for the default `FORMAT` locale.*" || (no idea what `v` is in posted code)

Comment: Thanks. Do we have any specify place we can find this `FORMAT` locale on windows or Java? (removed unwanted line)

Comment: What is your *real code*? You should be using `DateTimeFormatter`

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible, check this question and answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6743553/17758716.

Comment: Don't describe the code you think you need or the steps. Describe the [GOAL](http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/117-smart-questions)

Comment: The images don't help.   Please describe your problem in a paragraph or two and use simple formatted strings to show before, after, and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be asking the wrong question. If you send data to a client UI, send ISO Date and let the [intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) JS object handle the visualization. This will cater to the user's formatting preferences.

You can use the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) if you want to stay server side.

Also note: When your Domino server runs as a service, the **user** locale gets ignored and the **system** locale is used.

This [ServerVault entry](https://serverfault.com/questions/759278/force-locale-in-windows-services) and this [external support](https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000086159-how-to-change-your-windows-services-locale) shed some light on it.

I still would leave the rendering to front-end code.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, [external support](https://kb.firedaemon.com/support/solutions/articles/4000086159-how-to-change-your-windows-services-locale) worked. Ensure that "Welcome screen and system accounts" is checked, as well as "New user accounts". This ensures that locale settings are copied for existing users, system accounts (i.e. service accounts including domino) and new user accounts.